# Why is a GroupBy followed by a SelectMany to take the n latest records for that group not working without an extra select anonymous step?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

The question title was a bit difficult to write here but what I mean is:

This is working.

```
DataContext.Article.AsNoTracking()
.GroupBy(a => a.ArticleCategoryId)
.Select(group =>
    new {
        Articles = group.Take(3)
    })
.Select(x => x.Articles)
```

This is not working.

```
DataContext.Article.AsNoTracking()
.GroupBy(a => a.ArticleCategoryId)
.SelectMany(group => group.Take(3))
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
System.SharedTypeExtensions.GetSequenceType(Type type)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitMainFromClause(MainFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.LiftSubQuery(IQuerySource querySource, SubQueryExpression subQueryExpression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.CompileAdditionalFromClauseExpression(AdditionalFromClause additionalFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitAdditionalFromClause(AdditionalFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitAdditionalFromClause(AdditionalFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection<IBodyClause> bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.LiftSubQuery(IQuerySource querySource, SubQueryExpression subQueryExpression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.CompileJoinClauseInnerSequenceExpression(JoinClause joinClause, QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitJoinClause(JoinClause joinClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitJoinClause(JoinClause joinClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection<IBodyClause> bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.ExpressionVisitorBase.VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
```

I am really not sure what to make of this. My select anonymous type here seems like an arbitrary step but makes it work.

Comment: There are many query translation issues in EF Core not caused by one's (valid) code. However, are you sure that it really "makes it work"?  The type of  the result of the two queries is different - `.Select(x => x.Articles)` returns list of lists. In order to match the second it has to be `.SelectMany(x => x.Articles)`. You are lucky If it works - many current EF Core defects are solved with intermediate projection - it doesn't affect how the query is executed, so except some redundant typing, there is no problem. The real problem will be if it doesn't work.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes I realised that it isnt quite the same but I can flatten it out after putting it in memory so I am not that bothered by it.